# Core-menu On tap event not working on firefox

Tags: firefox, polymer

I just upgraded to 0.5.1 and core-menu is no longer working on firefox . Its working fine on other browsers but on firefox the menu items don't get selected. It doesn't recognize ontap event

Comment: [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/leluti/2/edit?html,console,output) of a demo that uses `<core-menu>` and seems to work fine from Firefox—I see the `on-tap` handler's logging. Please provide a runnable example illustrating the specific problem you're seeing.

Comment: It's an issue with firefox on linux. I was referring to https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/941. Anyways it seems to be working with the workaround suggested in the comments. Thanks!